# always argue or are always arguing

Tags: grammar

I am working on some grammar exercise.

> They don't get on well. They are always arguing.

According to answer key, 'are always arguing' is correct. Can you help why the correct answer is not 'always argue', but 'are always arguing'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right answer is "they always argue"

Because the first part of the sentence "they don't get on well" is present simple" so the following part should be the same. Furthermore, the processing of argument is constantly happening "always", so it implies to something that is not temporary but permanent.

Comment: Wrong. _They always argue_ means that they argue every time they meet. This might be true, but it's more common to use the continuous tense with the sense _They argue so often that it seems as though it is happening all the time_.